# Convergence of geometric series with |r|>1

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The geometric series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty ar^n$ with $a, r \in \mathbb{R}$ converges to $\frac{a}{1-r}$ iff $|r| < 1$.

Given this proof:

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty ar^n = a + \sum_{n=1}^\infty ar^n = a + r\sum_{n=0}^\infty ar^n$ [1],

where we can clear $\sum_{n=0}^\infty ar^n$ as

$(1-r) \sum_{n=0}^\infty ar^n = a$,

leading to

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty ar^n = \frac{a}{1-r} \blacksquare$,

my question is: where have been used the fact that $r$ must be $|r|<1$? To me, all the steps done in [1] are true no matter how $r$ is.

Comment: That "proof" is no proof at all - none of it makes any sense unless you already know the sum converges.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich why is that?

Comment: The proof doesn't seem to be that it is a proof of what the series converges to and seems to be taking it for granted that the series converges iff $|r| < 1$.  It should be obvious that the series does not converge if $|r| \ge 1$.  It wouldn't be hard to prove it converges if $|r| < 1$ but... this proof doesn't seem to bother.

Comment: The proof is incomplete.  It proves that when the series converges it does converge to $\frac a{1-r}$ but nothing more.  It does nothing to prove that it converges if and only if $|r| < 1$.

Comment: Where did you get this bizarre and unacceptable proof?

Comment: @fleablood I misunderstood it, it is actually a proof of _where_ it converges rather than _why_ it converges, so it's my fault (anyway I took it from wikipedia).

Comment: But it's not a proof of where it converges.  That is preciely what it *doesn't* prove.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This proof is not valid since the proof already assumes convergence. The following implication makes no sense

$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty ar^n = a + r\sum_{n=0}^\infty ar^n \implies (1-r) \sum_{n=0}^\infty ar^n = a$$

unless you assume the convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty ar^n$ (because assume it diverges, then $\sum_{n=0}^\infty ar^n$ is undefined. Can you do arithmetic with undefined objects?).

Here is a proof that $1=0$:
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty 1 = 1 + \sum_{n=0}^\infty 1 \implies 1=0$$

Comment: I wouldn't say it proves "nothing".  It proves if the series converges than it converges to $\frac a{1-r}$.  But that was the absolute *least* important thing that needed to be proven.  Obviously the most important thing to prove is *when* the series converges which this "proof" bizarrely seemed to blithely ignore.

Comment: Thank you, I will rephrase my statement.

Answer (score 4):

The proof is incomplete.

To be complete it must prove.

1) the series does not converge if $|r| \ge 1$.

2) the series converges if $|r| < 1$.

3) when the series converges it converges to $\frac a{1-r}$

The proof does 3) but totally ignores the first two.

The proper proof is to show find the limit of finite sums:

For finite $n$, $\sum_{i=0}^n ar^n$ can be shown to be equal to $a\frac {r^{n+1} - 1}{r-1}$ (assuming $r \ne 1$.  If $r=1$ then it is clear that $\sum ar^i = n*a$ which clearly diverges.)

(Because $(r-1)\sum\limits_{i=0}^n ar^n = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} (ar^{i+1} - ar^i) =\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n+1}ar^i - \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}ar^i=ar^{n+1} - 1$.)

This is continuous so $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i=0}^n ar^n=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}a\frac {r^{n+1} - 1}{r-1}$ which converges $a\frac {K - 1}{r-1}$ if and only if $r^{n+1}$ converges to $K$ and $r \ne 1$.

It's easy to show that $r^{n+1}$ converges to $0$ if $|r| < 1$, converges (is) $1$ if $r = 1$ (which we've ruled out for other reasons), and does not converge otherwise.

So $\sum_{i=0}^\infty ar^n = \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i=0}^n ar^n=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}a\frac {r^{n+1} - 1}{r-1}= a\frac {0 - 1}{r-1} = \frac a{1-r}$ if and only if $|r| < 1$.

Comment: (1) is false unless you assume that $a \ne 0$ (which is a trivial edge case, granted, but still needs to be explicitly excluded).

Comment: Yes, I guess so.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty ar^n = a + \sum_{n=1}^\infty ar^n = a + r\sum_{n=0}^\infty ar^n
$$

As several comments and answers point out, using the $\infty$'s in the sums *assumes* that the limits of the partial sums exist - that's the definition of an infinite sum.

What you can say is this identity for finite sums
$$
\sum_{n=0}^N ar^n = a + \sum_{n=1}^N ar^n = a + r\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} ar^{n+1}
$$

You can't finish your "proof" from here.

To summarize: if you somehow establish that the sum exists, then your argument correctly finds its value.

Answer (score 1):

If $r\geq 1$, then the sum diverges to $\infty$, and you can't subtract $\infty$ from $\infty$. If $r \leq -1$, then the sum does not exist.

Comment: I know that if $r>=1$ then in diverges to $\infty$, but I want to know, in such case, what is wrong with the proof given in my question.

Comment: @CarlosNavarroAstiasarán As I said, it fails when you are subtracting $\infty$ from $\infty$.

Comment: So ... that doesn't me if $|r|<1$ that the series converges.